# linux mint terminal does not execute commands given from Qt creator

Tags: c++, qt, linux-mint

Hy guys. I am new to Qt creator and now i am struggling with connecting it to Linux Mint 18 MATE terminal.  The problem is, i can open the terminal, but other commands just doesn't execute. Here is the code that I am trying -

```
void access::on_pushButton_clicked(){

  QProcess process;
  process.start("mate-terminal cd /tmp");
  process.write("ls -Al");
  process.closeWriteChannel();

  process.waitForFinished();
  QByteArray output = sh.readAll();
  process.close();
     }
```

All I need to do with this is -

1. open terminal
2. go to /tmp directory
3. print out the content

Any help or hint of what am I doing wrong would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Why not using QDir/QFileInfo to list files from /tmp ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you don't need the terminal UI in this case, so you wouldn't need to open `mate-terminal`, you should open the `sh` instead. Also note that after calling the `start` method you should `waitForStarted`.

```
QProcess process;
process.start("sh");
process.waitForStarted();
process.write("ls /tmp -Al");
process.closeWriteChannel();
process.waitForFinished();
QByteArray output = process.readAll();
process.close();
qDebug() << output;
```

**Note:** `sh` is a command line interpreter and has its own scripting language, if you only want to start `ls`, so you can start it *directly* without having to start `sh` at first.

```
QProcess process;
process.start("ls /tmp -Al");
process.waitForFinished();
QByteArray output = process.readAll();
process.close();
qDebug() << output;
```

Comment: Well, actually I need the terminal, because i have to tell it to do commands  trough Qt Creator and display the result in the terminal window. But thanks for the answer.

Comment: @Qtstruggler So, if you need terminal's window, why do you close it? (`process.close();`)